# how to find an anchor tag is clicked on current document in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to attach a click event at the document level with

```
 $(document).click();
```

And on clicking the element i would like to find out whether it is an anchor tag. If it is an anchor tag, then i will call a method to do something. How can that be done? Any idea?

Comment: Why do you want to do this, instead of `$("a").click(function() { ... });` ?

Comment: @Peter: hey seems like u din check my comment at the end of the page...  the problem was there are some 100's of links on a page and user clicks  on only one link. hence attaching click event for all the anchors seemed little heavy..!

Comment: Thanks. Can you observe a difference in performance between the two methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll just have to check the event object's target.

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
  var targ;
  if (!e) var e = window.event;
  if (e.target) targ = e.target;
  else if (e.srcElement) targ = e.srcElement;

  if ($(targ).is('a')) {
    // do your stuff
  }
});
```

(cross-browser code for getting the event target from [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#target))

Also, if you're going to attach also other event handlers to the links, make sure you use `event.preventDefault` instead of just returning `false` if you want to cancel the link's default action (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/javascript-event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)).

Answer (score 0):

How about just attaching this function you want to call to all of the anchor tags directly?

`$("a").click(function(){ alert("a link!") })`

Comment: I believe this adds a click event on all anchor tags that are there on the document, my user clicks on any one link and attaching click event for all the anchors sounded little heavy

Comment: @Amit You're right; just thought it made more sense to me than filtering document-wide clicks.  Looks like some other people knew more than me though :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#anchor">Anchor</a>
<a href="link">Anchor</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).click(function(event){
        if(event.target.nodeName === 'A'){
            alert('Anchor');
        } else{
            alert('Not an anchor');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

@kkyy: What will not work, is, if you are trying to make a request on that click event of that anchor, in Safari (all, windows, iPhone, etc.) e.g. in your code:

```
if ($(targ).is('a')) {
    var img = new Image(1,1);
    img.onload = function(){};
    img.src = "http://www.google.com/images/logos/somelogo.png?" + new Date().getTime();
  }
```

If you watch the traffic through any sniffer, you won't see the request above in Safari. Yes, pretty lame!